# How use simple_html_dom in laravel

Tags: php, html, dom, laravel-5, simple-html-dom

I want to use simple_html_dom in my Laravel project. but I can't add this package to my project.

How can I use simple_html_dom in laravel?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several ways, one of them using composer. Run this command from the command line:

```
composer require sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser
```

Example usage:

```
use Sunra\PhpSimple\HtmlDomParser;

$document = HtmlDomParser::str_get_html($html_text);
$document->find($selector);
```

Comment: This fails for php7.3 https://github.com/sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser/issues/75

Comment: Thank you!!!!   I've been having so many problems trying to get this to work in Laravel, until I found your solution!